# WPF Application as OLE server

Tags: .net, wpf, com, ole

I know that there are a lot of posts about this issue, but I've googled so much last five days and didn't find any working solution (and couldn't do it myself).

Could anybody upload a simple wpf application (may be a `TextBox` inside `Border`), which acts as an OLE server. For instance, I insert dll in MS Excel and see that `TextBox` inside `Border`.

Now I could do only such thing: I insert my dll in MS Word and see "[dll name].dll". Once I open an icon a window opens. But I want to have an embedded window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not.

[OLE Container for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139765/ole-container-for-net)

OLE is dead, was dead for years and should please be allowed to die also in your programs. C# never supported it.

Comment: I also want death for OLE. But it's my working task. You gave me a link to an opposite problem: embed OLE in WPF.

Comment: Well, for .NET OLE is dead. Point. Working task? ;) Well, have fun. OLE was never part of .NET. Will not be. It is dead technology.

Comment: I understand. But if I find any working sample it would be great.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you about this issue. If you have nothing to say - it's better to remain silent.